# Find the sign a permutation of $k+l$ elemements such that swaps the first $l$ elements with the last ones.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, permutations, combinations, permutation-cycles

A permutation $\sigma$ of $k$ elements $a_1,...,a_k$ is a one-to-one function from the set $A$ containing that elements to the same and in particular a trasposition is a permutation that swap only two elements. Now a permutation is even if an even number swappings is necessary to apply to obtain it and otherwise it is odd and in particular we say that the sign of a permutation is $1$ if it is even and it is $-1$ if the permutation is odd. So it is possible to prove that any permutation is the composition of a number $r$ of transpositions such that the quantity $(-1)^r$ is equal to the sign fo the permutation.

So if $\sigma$ is the permutation of $(k+l)$ elements that swaps the first $l$ elements of $A$ with the last ones, that is
$$
\sigma(1)=k+1,...,\sigma(l)=k+l,\sigma(l+1)=1,...,\sigma(k+l)=k
$$
then I ask to prove that its sign is $(-1)^{kl}$. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Another way to calculate the sign of a permutation is to count the number of inversions.

Comment: I think that the easiest approach is by way of [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)). If $N(\sigma)$ is the number of inversions in $\sigma$, then the sign of $\sigma$ is $(-1)^{N(\sigma)}$. There are several proofs of this; perhaps the most straightforward is [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation#Proof_4). Once you know that, you just have to show that $\sigma$ has $k\ell$ inversions. Looking at a few simple examples should make this fairly clear. E.g., with $k=6$ and $\ell=3$ you have $\sigma=456789123$.

Comment: Oh, yeha! Indeed if $i\le l$ then $\sigma(i)=k+i\ge j=\sigma(l+j)$ for each $j=1,...,k$ and so for any $i=1,...,l$ there are $k$ inversion, right?